# Self Hosted Github Actions Machine running out of Disk Space in a few hours

Tags: docker, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

We put together a very powerful machine at my company for CI, using GitHub Actions. It's a very powerful machine, so we have ~15 Github Actions runners, running directly on the linux machine. We also run all of our jobs using the container syntax. i.e.

```
  build-js-servers:
    name: Build JS Servers
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, docker ]
    container:
      image: node:16
```

We're running into an issue now where we are creating so many dangling containers, our device is running out of space in a few hours. We have a nightly build that runs `docker system prune --all -f` on the machine, but it appears to not be enough.

All the containers or images that github actions creates though are pointless, waste space, and unnecessarily wear out our SSD. Is there a way we can configure the temporary containers not to be saved to disk at all? That would be an ideal solution.

Comment: Wouldn't that add to the docker build time in the absence of cached images? You may schedule another daily job for pruning.